# How to make only artifacts from my Jenkins server public?

Tags: jenkins

I've set up a new Jenkins server earlier today.
When I open `localhost:8080/jenkins`, it prompts me for a username and password.
I enter mine in, and from there I can view my dashboard, including the projects I've set up, and their artifacts.
However, I would like people to be able to download the artifacts of my projects, **without** an account.
But that's the only thing I would like to allow them to do.  View my artifacts, and nothing else, unless they have an account.

*So, how do I set this up?*

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actually pretty *simple*.
Go to `Manage Jenkins`, then `Configure Global Security`.
Then check:

- Enable security
- Jenkins' own user database (in Access Control -> Security Realm)
- Logged-in users can do anything (as well as Allow anonymous read access) [both are in Access Control -> Authorization]

Once that's done, other people should be able to view your artifacts.

Comment: Do you also have an answer if Access Control is "Active Directory Authentication"?